# Characteristics of the set $ A = (0,1) \cup \{ 1 + 1/n : n \in N\}$ on $R$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For the set A, I have the following thoughts that I want to verify:

1. A is neither closed nor open on $R$. It isn't open as take for example $x = 1.5, r = 0.1$, then $x \in A$ but $B_r(x)$ (open ball centered at x) is not a subset of A. A is not closed as it doesn't contain all of it's limit points, for example, it doesn't contain $x=\{ 1\}$.
2. The limit points of A are $[0,1]$
3. int $A$ = $(0,1)$, (closure) $\overline{A} = [0,1]$, $\partial A = \{ 0, 1\} \cup  \{ 1 + 1/n  : n \in N\}$

If we then consider the set $A$ relative to $(0, \infty)$ instead, then the limit points are instead $(0,1]$, the interior points remain the same, the closure is $(0,1]$, and $\partial A = \{ 1\} \cup  \{ 1 + 1/n  : n \in N\}$

I'm wondering if this is correct, or if there are any issues with my reasoning?

**typo which was pointed out in one of the answers**

In the first case, it should be : 
$\overline{A} = [0,1]\cup  \{ 1 + 1/n  : n \in N\}$

and in the second:
$\overline{A} = (0,1]\cup  \{ 1 + 1/n  : n \in N\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of $A$ always contains *all* elements of $A$ (not only the limitpoints).

We have $\overline A=A\cup A'$ where $A'$ denotes the collection of limit points of $A$.

So also the elements $1+\frac1n$ in this case.

Further it is correct.

Comment: sorry, that was actually a typo, i meant to put that in. So you are sying apart from that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, the things that are stated (though not all proved) are correct now.